# Colocando imagem com em um componente do React

Tags: javascript, html, react

Estou utilizando um componente do React com o seguinte código:

```
import React from 'react'
import './styles.css'
import logo from './icons/logo.svg'
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome'
import { faMapMarkerAlt, faShoppingBag } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons'


const Header = () => 
    <header id="main-header">
        <div id="header-topo">
            <div className="icon">
                <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMapMarkerAlt} />
            </div>
            <div className="texto-esquerda flex-item-1">
                Nossas Lojas
            </div>
            <nav className="texto-direita flex-item-1 crumbs">
                <ol>
                    <li className="crumb">My Blue's 0</li>
                    <li className="crumb icon"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingBag} /></li>
                    <li className="crumb cadastre-se">Sign in | Cadastre-se</li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
        <div id="header-med">
            <nav className="texto-centro flex-item-1 crumbs">
                <ol>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Feminino</li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Masculino</li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Mini</li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav img-logo"><img src="{logo}" alt="Alguma coisa"/></li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Gifts</li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Brides</li>
                    <li className="crumb item-nav">Sale</li>

                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>;

export default Header;
```

a imagem não carrega e o console apresenta o erro que não estou usando o import do "logo", alguém poderia me ajudar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu `import` retorna uma variável, não precisa usar as `"`

```
<img src={logo} alt="Alguma coisa"/>
```

Comment: Perfeito era esse erro mesmo, valeuuu!